# Why the asp-controller no work in the form tag helper?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I followed the tutorial of https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mU4hV50rkVE&list=PL6n9fhu94yhVkdrusLaQsfERmL_Jh4XmU&index=40

As the video showed, there is an asp-controller attribute in the form tag helper as below:
[image]

However, I can't find it in my visual studio:
[image]

Although I still type the attribute inside the form tag helper.
 After it compiled, the tutorial showed the source-code in the browser:
[image]

Meanwhile, there is mine. It is much more different from the tutorial:
[image]

I am using the VS 2019 16.2.4 and .net core 2.2. What's wrong with this. How can I solve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add below line in `_ViewImports.cshtml` to add `TagHelper` support :

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

The purpose of the `_ViewImports.cshtml` file is to provide a mechanism to make directives available to  pages globally so that you don't have to add them to pages individually.